# Desktop Advertisement API

Tags: windows, c#, api, wpf, advertising

I am looking for a simple advertisement API that works with C# and WPF. I looked on the internet some, and all I have been able to find is that people want to use Google's advertisement API is not allowed on desktop apps. Is that true? If not, are there other options out there that are simple enough to use? I know that the windows 8 mobile platform used to have a control that you could drag and drop and get ads from, but that seems to not be part of WPF. This is for a desktop application, and I do not have the resources to create servers if that matters at all. Thanks